# Matrix column with list field type

Tags: matrix, list, custom-fields

We're integrating a new client site that has a rather unique need. We have a matrix field with two columns. The second column needs to be output in the template in a list format (LI tags). Originally we planned on integrating P&T List for the second column but we found that it doesn't allow carriage returns, which is another requirement.

Here's the template we'll be integrating:

http://www.itistic.com/projects/radiologyassociates/html/radiologists/kedar.asp

We're using Matrix to output custom designations for each radiologist. In the page above, the USF Associate Professor list would be an example of a custom designation. So in our Custom Designations Matrix field we'd have the following columns:

```
USF Associate Professor   |   - Body Imaging
                              - Musculoskeletal
```

.. and here's another example:

http://www.itistic.com/projects/radiologyassociates/html/radiologists/feldman.asp

In this entry, the Cross Sectional Imaging Fellowship would be a custom designation that's input via this Matrix field. You can see here that we need the ability to do line breaks/carriage returns in a single list item.

```
Cross Sectional Imaging Fellowship   |   - Mayo Clinic
                                           Jacksonville, FL
                                           Body Imaging
```

Any options?

Comment: Shawn, was there a correct answer to this question posted?

Comment: Yes, Anna. Sorry - just marked the answer I ended up using now :)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

[Markdown](https://github.com/experience/smartdown.ee_addon) is probably worth considering, although users would familiarise themselves with the two-trailing-spaces linebreak behaviour, which isn't exactly intuitive.

If you're using WYSIWYG fields elsewhere that's also an option. For example, you could easily setup a [Wygwam](http://pixelandtonic.com/wygwam) editor config which only has the bulleted list control enabled. That would be crazy-simple and fairly robust, as users aren't going to start screwing around with other controls that might make a mess of the layout.

Comment: I like the WYSIWYG approach! Hadn't even thought about that. Great idea!

Comment: Tip: If you were to use Wygwam you could set up a custom WYSIWYG layout which only has bullet points and no other controls which may leave your page a bit fugly looking.

Comment: @AndieFairlie That's exactly what I suggested.

Comment: @DomStubbs so you did! Sorry!!

Comment: @AndieFairlie No worries. Great minds, etc.

Answer (score 6):

Not the best though, maybe use 3 columns:

- Title
- [PT List](http://devot-ee.com/add-ons/pt-list)
- [Nolan](http://devot-ee.com/add-ons/nolan)

Then do something like the following:

```
<ul>
    {your_matrix_field}
        <h3>{mx_text_title}</h3>

        {if mx_nolan_items}
            <ul>
                <li>
                    {!-- single line so our backspace isn't having to count blank spaces --}
                    {mx_nolan_items backspace='4'}{nolan_item}<br>{/mx_nolan_items}
                </li>
            </ul>
        {/if}

        {if mx_ptlist_items}
            {mx_ptlist_items}
        {/if}

    {/your_matrix_field}
</ul>
```

Make sure you explain in the field directions or via [NSM Publish Hints](http://devot-ee.com/add-ons/nsm-publish-hints) that they should only use the list or the nolan for each row. So only one or the other vs both at once.

Comment: Never knew about Nolan. Looks to be a useful add-on. Thanks for the suggestion!!

Answer (score 2):

Are you using Low Variables? you can put a low variable, which contains a matrix field, inside a matrix and that would theoretically give you the list that you need inside that cell. I haven't tried this myself, but it should work.

Alternatively you could check out [Nolan](http://devot-ee.com/add-ons/nolan), which lets you have a simple matrix inside a matrix.

Comment: Never knew about Nolan. Looks to be a useful add-on. Thanks for the suggestion!!